# Reading / Writing from a Unix Socket in Ruby

Tags: ruby, unix-socket

I'm trying to connect, read and write from a UNIX socket in Ruby. It is a stats socket used by haproxy.

My code is the following:

```
require 'socket'
socket = UNIXSocket.new("/tmp/haproxy.stats.socket")

# First attempt: works

socket.puts("show stat")

while(line = socket.gets) do
  puts line
end

# Second attemp: fails

socket.puts("show stat")

while(line = socket.gets) do
  puts line
end
```

It succeeds the first time, but on the second attempt fails. I'm not sure why.

```
# pxname,svname,qcur,qmax,scur,smax,slim,stot,bin,bout,dreq,dresp,ereq,econ,eresp,wretr,wredis,status,weight,act,bck,chkfail,chkdown,lastchg,downtime,qlimit,pid,iid,sid,throttle,lbtot,tracked,type,rate,rate_lim,rate_max,check_status,check_code,check_duration,hrsp_1xx,hrsp_2xx,hrsp_3xx,hrsp_4xx,hrsp_5xx,hrsp_other,hanafail,req_rate,req_rate_max,req_tot,cli_abrt,srv_abrt,
stats,FRONTEND,,,0,0,2000,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,OPEN,,,,,,,,,1,1,0,,,,0,0,0,0,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,,0,0,0,,,
stats,BACKEND,0,0,0,0,2000,0,0,0,0,0,,0,0,0,0,UP,0,0,0,,0,22,0,,1,1,0,,0,,1,0,,0,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,0,0,
legacy_socket,FRONTEND,,,0,0,1000,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,OPEN,,,,,,,,,1,2,0,,,,0,0,0,0,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,,0,0,0,,,
all,FRONTEND,,,0,0,10000,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,OPEN,,,,,,,,,1,3,0,,,,0,0,0,0,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,,0,0,0,,,
socket_backend,socket,0,0,0,0,200,0,0,0,,0,,0,0,0,0,DOWN,1,1,0,0,1,22,22,,1,4,1,,0,,2,0,,0,L4CON,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,0,0,
socket_backend,socket,0,0,0,0,200,0,0,0,,0,,0,0,0,0,DOWN,1,1,0,0,1,22,22,,1,4,2,,0,,2,0,,0,L4CON,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,0,0,
socket_backend,socket,0,0,0,0,200,0,0,0,,0,,0,0,0,0,DOWN,1,1,0,0,1,22,22,,1,4,3,,0,,2,0,,0,L4CON,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,0,0,
socket_backend,socket,0,0,0,0,200,0,0,0,,0,,0,0,0,0,DOWN,1,1,0,0,1,22,22,,1,4,4,,0,,2,0,,0,L4CON,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,0,0,
socket_backend,socket,0,0,0,0,200,0,0,0,,0,,0,0,0,0,DOWN,1,1,0,0,1,22,22,,1,4,5,,0,,2,0,,0,L4CON,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,0,0,
socket_backend,socket,0,0,0,0,200,0,0,0,,0,,0,0,0,0,DOWN,1,1,0,0,1,22,22,,1,4,6,,0,,2,0,,0,L4CON,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,0,0,
socket_backend,socket,0,0,0,0,200,0,0,0,,0,,0,0,0,0,DOWN,1,1,0,0,1,22,22,,1,4,7,,0,,2,0,,0,L4CON,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,0,0,
socket_backend,socket,0,0,0,0,200,0,0,0,,0,,0,0,0,0,DOWN,1,1,0,0,1,21,21,,1,4,8,,0,,2,0,,0,L4CON,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,0,0,
socket_backend,socket,0,0,0,0,200,0,0,0,,0,,0,0,0,0,DOWN,1,1,0,0,1,21,21,,1,4,9,,0,,2,0,,0,L4CON,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,0,0,
socket_backend,socket,0,0,0,0,200,0,0,0,,0,,0,0,0,0,DOWN,1,1,0,0,1,21,21,,1,4,10,,0,,2,0,,0,L4CON,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,0,0,
socket_backend,BACKEND,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,0,0,0,0,DOWN,0,0,0,,1,21,21,,1,4,0,,0,,1,0,,0,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,0,0,
api_backend,api,0,0,0,0,200,0,0,0,,0,,0,0,0,0,UP,1,1,0,0,0,22,0,,1,5,1,,0,,2,0,,0,L4OK,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,0,0,
api_backend,api,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,,0,,0,0,0,0,UP,1,1,0,0,0,22,0,,1,5,2,,0,,2,0,,0,L4OK,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,0,0,
api_backend,api,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,,0,,0,0,0,0,DOWN,1,1,0,0,1,21,21,,1,5,3,,0,,2,0,,0,L4CON,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,0,0,
api_backend,BACKEND,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,0,0,0,0,UP,2,2,0,,0,22,0,,1,5,0,,0,,1,0,,0,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,0,0,
www_backend,ruby-www,0,0,0,0,10000,0,0,0,,0,,0,0,0,0,UP,1,1,0,0,0,22,0,,1,6,1,,0,,2,0,,0,L4OK,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,0,0,
www_backend,BACKEND,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,0,0,0,0,UP,1,1,0,,0,22,0,,1,6,0,,0,,1,0,,0,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,0,0,

/Users/Olly/Desktop/haproxy_stats.rb:14:in `write': Broken pipe (Errno::EPIPE)
    from /Users/Olly/Desktop/haproxy_stats.rb:14:in `puts'
    from /Users/Olly/Desktop/haproxy_stats.rb:14
```

What is the problem? Is there a good reference to using UNIX sockets and Ruby?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the connection has been closed after the first request. I don't think you are doing anything wrong. The HAProxy stats socket is probably designed so that it responds to a single command and then closes the connection.

I think you need to reconnect for each request.

If you look at [this blog post](http://www.joeandmotorboat.com/2009/08/20/haproxy-stats-socket-and-fun-with-socat/) which is about using HAProxy stats socket with [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) then this makes sense because you pipe the `show stat` command into socat and socat reads from the socket until it closes.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I need to read up on how UNIX sockets work. I was expecting it to work like a TCPSocket that stayed open.

Comment: One of the things I don't get is when I use socat, then I ALWAYS get the results returned from the socket, however when I do this via the ruby code above, every now and then I don't get ANY data returned from HAproxy...so I have to run several times...some dodgy stuff in Ruby's socket implementation I guess.

Answer (score 14):

Olly,

HAproxy closes connection after the first request unless you use the "prompt" command (see http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt section 9.2) :

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby                                                                                                                         

require 'socket'                                                                                                                            

socket = UNIXSocket.new("/tmp/haproxy.stats.socket")                                                                                            

# Goes interactive mode
socket.puts("prompt")                                                                                                                       

# Ask statistics every second                                                                                                                             
while true                                                                                                                                  
  socket.puts("show stat")                                                                                                                  
  socket.each_char do |c|
    # We had the prompt, break out                                                                                                   
    break if c == '>'                                                                                                                       
    print c                                                                                                                                 
  end                                                                                                                                       

  sleep 1                                                                                                                                   
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered the same problem when use `socket.puts`, you can use `socket.write` instead of `socket.puts` to fix it.

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/evn ruby
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

require 'rubygems'
require 'uri'
require 'socket'
require 'yaml'

SOCKET = URI.parse("/var/run/haproxy/haproxy.sock")

def get_info
  UNIXSocket.open(SOCKET.path) do |socket|
    socket.write("show info;")
    info = YAML::load socket
    #info.each {|key, value| puts "#{key} ➤ #{value}"}
  end
end

puts get_info["Uptime_sec"]
```

Look this [gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/haproxy) for more information, source code is [here](https://github.com/inkel/haproxy-ruby).

Answer (score 0):

You can use man socket. You can use the socket-class just like you would if it was a C-function.

I found man-pages to be very useful.